# How to set form action results displayed in diago?

Tags: php, jquery

Suppose I have some form like this in `index.php`:

```
<form  method="get" name="s" action="search.php" id="s"> 
<input type="text"  name="email" size="25" />
<input type="submit" name="ss" value="search" id="ss"/>
</form>
```

which will submit the input email to `search.php` when cilck `search` button.

My problem is that how to show the results (obtained from `search.php`, and it should also be considered that the `email` should be submit to the `search.php` page) in a dialog by jquery?

Thanks!

--EDIT:Improved--

```
$(document).ready(function () {
        $('#s').on("submit", function(e){
                e.preventDefault();
                $.get("search.php",$(this).serialize(), function(data){
                        //alert(data);
                        $('<div></div>').html(data).dialog({
                                autoopen: false,
                                modal: false,
                                width: 900,
                                height: 300
                                }).dialog('open');
                });
        });
});
```

I believe my code is write here, but it seems I have no output, why?

Answer (score 1):

```
$("#s").on("submit",function(e){
e.preventDefault();
$.get("search.php",$(this).serialize(),function(data){
alert(data);//or do whatever you want!
});
});
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, but could you help me agian to out put the results in a dialog of jquery?

Comment: you mean a modal window? If yes then search for how to make a modal window in jquery or use a jquery plugin for the same.